# Редактирование данных в форме

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Нужно сделать, чтобы в форме редактировались введенные данные. Есть функция

```
function pageedit($id, $title, $text, $dt_edit)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE pages SET title='$title', text='$text' where id='$id'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

А также сама форма

```
$sel = onepage($id);
foreach ($sel as $item){
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Редактировать страницу</title>
<body>
<p>Редактировать страницу</p>
<form action="savepage.php" method="post" >
Title  <input type="text" name="title" size="100" value="<?=$item["title"]?>"/><br>
Text   <textarea cols="100" rows="20" name="text"> <?=$item["text"]?></textarea>
       <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: @kira, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @kira и что дальше? Толи мне кажется, толи все зделано задом на перед...

Comment: Создаете несколько страничек в одном окне? о_О

    foreach ($sel as $item){
    ?>
    <html>...</html>
    <?
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не передается у вас `$_GET["id"];`

И что за value у тега form?

Comment: 2 @Palmervan, точно, не обратил внимание сразу.

2 @kira, в общем элементы формы как минимум надо подучить )

Comment: и как правильно делается? я просто не знаю.

Comment: @DemoS рано я снес коммент) у `textarea` это одно, у `form` это второе. Но как я понял тот атрибут предназначен для `input type="text"`

З.Ы. Круто быть экстрасенсом)

Comment: 2 @kira, вот про формы много чего написано [html формы][1]


  [1]: http://www.softtime.ru/article/index.php?id_article=96

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: форму я исправила, только теперь когда вызываю функцию изменения, она полностью удаляет всю запись

Comment: Потому что `$_GET["id"]` у вас по-прежнему не передается. Исправьте action в теге form

    action="savepage.php?id=<?=$item["id"]?>"

И сам запрос:

    $sql = "UPDATE pages SET title='$title', text='$text' where id=".intval($id);

UPD: И я не вижу, что вы исправили форму

Comment: все сделала, спасибо большое.

Comment: Не забывайте принимать ответ, если он вас устроил. (галочка слева от ответа)